# Is there a markdown parser supported on Jekyll that plays nicely with mathjax?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, mathjax

I use a Jekyll based blog and need a markdown parser that won't clobber my Mathjax expressions (for instance, interpreting `b_t - b_{t-1}` as `b<em>t - b</em> t - 1`).  Mathjax and markdown get along nicely over on math.stackechange.com and mathoverflow.net. Some parsers also need to double escape the begin/end equation symbols `\\(`, while it seems others do not.

**Things that aren't quite solutions:**

[Redcarpet2](https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet) has an option for `no_intra_emphasis`, which avoids underscores between letters being clobbered, so `b_t` is okay, but it still clobbers `b_{t-1}`.

There's a Jekyll plugin that lets you use liquid syntax, like `{% m}%` to begin an equation, but this means the file is no longer written in pure markdown and thus not portable to other contexts.

So is there a different markdown interpreter I can drop into Jekyll and experience bliss?  If not, what workarounds have others found?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Markdown won't process anything in block-level HTML tag, so simply wrapping Mathjax syntax in `<div>` `</div>` protects the Mathjax syntax, regardless of the interpreter.  This nicely avoids having to escape the commands that begin and end the Mathjax, such as `\(` (inline) and `\[` (display).  Thanks to [@lsegal](https://github.com/lsegal) on Github for pointing this out to me.

Comment: And `<span>` for inline maths.

Comment: @dbaupp no, span tags won't work, as discussed in your cboettig's github issue: https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet/issues/130. But I've got Redcarpet working for a while, see my response

Comment: I've since found that using Pandoc in mathjax mode (in which equations are delimited by `$` inline and `$$` display, as in original TeX, and rendered to html as `\(` and `\[` in mathjax mode) to be most reliable.  Config notes here: http://www.carlboettiger.info/README.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes there's and it's [kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org), I've gone through the process of configuring it and it's explained at [my blog](http://oblita.com/blog/2012/07/06/octopress-with-mathjax-by-kramdown/). I've also found you can get Redcarpet to accept inline math using the syntax `\\( some math \\)`. It'll output `\( math \)`to MathJax. Anyway, I prefer kramdown as it states to support LaTeX.

Comment: Haven't gotten fenced code blocks working with kramdown though.  Of course we could solve both these problems with liquid tags instead, but then the source-code isn't any flavor of markdown.

Comment: @cboettig I also haven't got it to work with Redcarpet, as I explain there. I've got a blank screen with fenced code blocks with 2.1.1, don't know the cause. And haven't gone deep to solve it...

Comment: Your blog link is broken.