# Math equation transform not properly (MathJax)

Tags: latex, mathjax, ace-editor, pagedown

I'm integrating Pagedown-ace and MathJax to develop a Authoring website.
Following is my question:

I tried to transform some equations which are the following

1. `$$ \text{ED}_{t+1} = f(\text{ED} $$`
2. `$$ \text{ED}_{t+1} = f(\text{ED}, \text{ED}, \text{ED}_{t-2},
   \text{ED}_{t-3},\dots, \text{error}) $$`

The first equation can transform using MathJax properly but the second one cannot. Can anyone point out what is the problem there? When I puts `<div>` tags around the second equation, it properly transform. I'm confused about what happen?

Thanks

Comment: MathJax interprets both equations without problem on [math.se].

Comment: Markdown languages (like Pagedown) don't play nice with MathJax because they turn underscores into `<em>...</em>` before the page is processed by MathJax, and MathJax doesn't think it is math any longer since it contains HTML tags.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438937/is-there-a-markdown-parser-supported-on-jekyll-that-plays-nicely-with-mathjax) for an example and alternatives.

Comment: You might want to say what you did (perhaps self-answer the question) so that others can benefit in the future.  That is, after all, the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem! The problem is that Pagedown turn the uderscores into `<em>...</em>`. Hence, the MathJax library cannot transform the text between `$$...$$` very properly.

My solution is: Get into the converter code which Pagedown transform the markdown into HTML, specified additional regular expression for the text between dollar sign and make them not to be convert into italic text by Pagedown.